# Intuition on why the derivative of the distribution functions equals the density function.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

if anybody could provide any intuition into why the derivative of the distribution functions is equal to the density function.

I am having some trouble with using distribution functions to calculate functions of random variables and I think that part of my issue comes from confusion over notation and also the basic ideas that are required to understand this.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I would say the intuition mainly goes the other way: the integral of the density function is the distribution function. Then we apply the fundamental theorem of calculus to get your claim.

Comment: I guess your response makes me realize I don't really even understand the difference between a density and distribution function. Does the density function refer to a specific interval within the distribution function?

Comment: When you say distribution function of a random variable $X$, i think about the function $F(x)=P(X\leq x)$, which is a monotone, increasing function, going from $0$ as $x\to-\infty$ to $1$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: You could think of it in terms of "units," that is the gradient represents distribution per a certain length which is the dimension of (linear) density.

Comment: There's a Khan video that may help https://www.khanacademy.org/math/statistics-probability/random-variables-stats-library/random-variables-continuous/v/probability-density-functions

Answer (score 5):

The *cummulative distribution function* (CDF) for a real-valued random variable (say, $X$) is the probability mass for the outcome being in the lower semi-infinite interval inclusively below the argument value.   Or less mouth fillingly:  $$F_X(x) ~=~ \mathbb P(X\in (-\infty;x])$$

If the random variable is continuous, then the *probability density function* (pdf) is the differenciation at this point; intutively it is the rate of change of the probability mass.$$f_X(x) ~=~\dfrac{\mathrm d ~F_X(x)}{\mathrm d ~x\qquad}$$

More typically defined the other way around.  $$F_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f_X(x)\operatorname d x$$

---

Similarly to defining inertial mass in terms of density in a volume: $m = \iiint_V \rho(x,y,z)\operatorname d z\operatorname d y\operatorname d x$